# customize nivo slider with a percent to make full background

Tags: html, css

These codes works perfectly but when I use `width: 100% and height: 100%` it doesn't work. Why?

```
 .slider-wrapper,.nivoSlider img{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
}
```

Is there a way to make the image full background-size?

Comment: The containers that surround this should also be set to 100%, along with `body` and `html`.

Comment: thanks. but when I set its width and height to 100% or any in % it doesn't show its image.